# How to solve the following system of PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a system of PDEs

> > $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i a(t)f, \qquad (1)$
> >
> > $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i f, \qquad (2) $
> >
> > where $f=f(x,\;y,\;t).$

How to solve this system?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think would be the first step? Is this a homework task?

Comment: No, it is not homework. I am trying to solve it by using the method of characteristics, but not able to find the answer like $f=e^{\int[{k_{1}-ia(t)]dt}+k_{1}x+(k_{1}-i)y}$, where $k_{1}$ is constant.

Comment: Hint: Methods of characteristics definitely works.